# Aligning Divs By Floating Right

Tags: html, css, code-formatting

Im having trouble getting some divs to float and align properly.

I have two divs that contain images that are working properly, and I need to add two more, with images that behave the in the same manner.

I tried to use the same code to make the current divs work properly, but they automatically seem to remain allocate themselves within the same div as the other images that I'm trying to use.

//Here is the Code.

```
<div id="products">
        <img src="cbdog.jpg" style="float: left; padding-bottom: 25px;">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="otherProducts">
        <br>
        <br>
    <img src="gelog.jpg" style="float: left;">
    </div>
```

Im trying to this is inline obvisouly.

So I tried to do.

```
<div id="products">
        <img src="cbdog.jpg" style="float: left; padding-bottom: 25px;">
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="otherProducts">
        <br>
        <br>
    <img src="gelog.jpg" style="float: left;">
    </div>
<div id="cbdGel">
        <br>
        <br>
    <img src="gelog.jpg" style="float: left;">
    </div>
```

And Basically replicate the previous formatting to get the same result, but the resulting image just places itself with the same div as the top image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

~zaklikescode

Comment: `<br/>` tags are used only in `<p></p>` tags. Not for alignement nor designing webpages. `ID`s must also be unique.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can reproduce the issue in a fiddle.

Comment: @D4V1D i used a generic name with the id. i actually used a name in the html. Ill edit that.

Comment: @Lal how can i create a fiddle? sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @D4V1Dignorant again. can i post the fiddle, or is it live stream?

Comment: make a fiddle and please share the link with us..

Comment: okay. 1 moment please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=ibSd9s4SPb here is there link for the fiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want two divs side by side? if so. You'll need to assign a width and position either inline using the `style=""` attribute or in css

```
#products, #otherproducts { float:left; width:48%; position:absolute; }
```

if not, let me know. I'll see what i can do.

Comment: will this put the image under the previous image. without occupying the same space.

Comment: if you change the width to 100% yes or more than 50% for each div. If you want them smaller than 50%, you'll need to assign a larger margin (left and right) refer to: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: i basically want 5 divs. stacked vertically, all floated left, with some marginal padding, that i can add later.

Comment: place your divs, one by one, position them absolute and place a margin that equates to the width of 100% (adding the size with the margin = 100%) pushing each div below one another add margin top or <br/> to add space between each of them.

Comment: if you need any more help, let me know